# How to pick a number in a document and turn it into a variable?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a beginner in using VBA. Also English is not my native language, so sorry in advance for any error.

I'm trying to pick a number that's inside a rectangle and turn this number into the value of a variable.

What i did so far:

```
Sub
    
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 7")).Select
    
    Dim v1 As Integer
    
    v1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 7")).Type
       
    Dim v2 As Integer
   
    v2 = v1 + 1
    
    Selection.TypeText Text:=v2
End Sub
```

---

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 7")).Type
```

that's the part i'm struggling the most.

Right now it's not showing any error, but it does nothing.

I want the rectangle to have a value inside, let's say 1. Then, when i run the macro i want it to make 1 equals the value of v1, then make the sum (v2) and show the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but here is some code which might help. Note that the rectangle content is returned as a string. In this example ... v1 is set to the numeric value of the content of the rectangle shape (e.g. the rectangle could contain the character **1**). It then assigns to v2, v1 + 1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetRectangleValueAndAddOne()
    
    Dim v1 As Integer
    Dim v2 As Integer
    
    v1 = Val(ActiveDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 7").TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
    v2 = v1 + 1
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The Val() function converts a numeric text string to a number of Double datatype, meaning it can accept decimals. The Integer data type can accept whole numbers only, with a range from about -32000 to +32000. Assigning a double to an integer may cause a `Data Type` error under some conditions. Therefore you might be better off declaring v1 As Double and then converting that to an integer when you calculate, like `v2 = Int(v1) + 1`, after making sure that v1 really holds the kind of value you expect.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler I didn't know that function, but it was exactly what i was looking for. I only found videos about VBA used for Excel. Thank you.